# Why can't MyEtherWallet automatically detect new tokens and their decimals, just like EtherScan?

Tags: tokens, myetherwallet, etherscan, user-experience

I'm just wondering whether it's practically not possible? Because on EtherScan, all my tokens are automatically listed, and when I choose one, I see the contract address and the number of decimals. Why do I have to add these manually on MyEtherWallet?

Answer (score 1):

MyEtherWallet is a simple wallet, it allows checking balance and sending new transaction. But it doesn't track old transactions. It is a simple service to maintain. Everyone can deploy their own instance!

Etherscan is a block explorer, it traces all transactions in mined blocks. It is a much more complex service, for example it needs several databases to store processed transactions. Developing and maintenance are more costly accordingly.

Comment: I hear what you're saying, but MEW also can use other network services to read accounts. Why else does it have the top-right corner choice of the network?

Comment: You will have to ask to MEW developers for their reasons. But relying in a third party service can be complex, if it is down or their data is outdated, your users will suffer.